# Express validator customization issue

Tags: node.js, express

I am new to Nodejs and I am writing Rest API's in nodejs using express framework. Now I make seperate route file,Controller File and validation file I simply call the route and post data via postman request. Now issue is that my request body format is little bit different from express-validator default library format.

**Post Requets Body**

```
{
    "data":{
         "local_db_path":"",
         "source_type":"google",
         "source_id":"ChIJTTuarbcFGTkRRJn1sPgP0SU",
         "short_code":"VvsyTY",
         "box_ids":[527],
         "text_content":""
    }
}
```

Route.js

```
const PostController = require('./controllers/PostController');
const { createPostRules } = require('./rules/CreatePost');
// create post route
router.post('/post/create-quick-post',createPostRules,PostController.createPost);
```

Validation rules js file

```
const {check, validationResult} = require('express-validator');
createPostRules = [      
    check('local_db_path').isEmpty().withMessage('Post Key is missing'),
    check('source_type').isEmpty().withMessage('Post source type missing'),
    check('source_type').isIn(['google', 'imdb']).withMessage('Invalid source type missing'),
    check('source_id').isEmpty().withMessage('Post source key missing'),
    check('box_ids').isEmpty().withMessage('Box Information is missing')
];
module.exports = { createPostRules }
```

Now the problem is that when I call the api route then this validation does not work because I am sending data in **request.body.data**

is there any other way that how I can use express validator with my current structure.

Answer (score 0):

You can always create your custom middleware for express, the middleware will flatten you body object

from:

```
{
    "data":{
         "local_db_path":"",
         "source_type":"google",
         "source_id":"ChIJTTuarbcFGTkRRJn1sPgP0SU",
         "short_code":"VvsyTY",
         "box_ids":[527],
         "text_content":""
    }
}
```

to:

```
{
  "local_db_path": "",
  "source_type": "google",
  "source_id": "ChIJTTuarbcFGTkRRJn1sPgP0SU",
  "short_code": "VvsyTY",
  "box_ids": [
    527
  ],
  "text_content": ""
}
```

The middleware

```
function flattenBodyData(req, res, next) {
  req.body = req.body.data ? req.body.data : {};
  next();
}
```

Using:

```
router.post(
  '/post/create-quick-post',
  flattenBodyData, // Here, before call createPostRules
  createPostRules, 
  PostController.createPost,
);
```

But in the next handler, like `PostController.createPost`. If you want to get `source_type` from body, syntax will be `req.body.source_type` instead of `req.body.data.source_type`

I have a suggestion, if your post body just have only `data` property, just "flatten" it from client side.